# Title was edited: is it still the same question?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the title of [my question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/73126/revisions) was edited from

> Is there a voltage in pin?

to

> Can I power peripherials from the 5V pins?

IMHO this changes the meaning of the question, but I'd like to ask the community, since I'm not a native English speaker.

My question is about powering the Raspberry via a GPIO pin. The direction of current is into the Raspberry. The new question title for me means: power the Raspberry normally and power the peripherals from the GPIO pin. That would mean the current flow goes out of the Raspberry. That's not what I wanted to know. I did that multiple times already.

Comment: I'd suggest the motive here was that the original title was very murky on an otherwise good question, although of course the new one was based on a misreading.  I've since re-titled it *Can I power a Pi through a 5V pin?* -- but you are again welcome to roll that back if you find it offensive ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't think that edit preserves the meaning. You're asking "Can I power the Pi from the 5V pins?" rather than "Can I power a peripheral from the pins?", which is a different issue. The title doesn't really describe your question accurately any more, so I'd suggest reverting it.

You can [roll back](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/73126/revisions) any edits you disagree with in the revision history, and it might also be a good idea to edit your post further, as it might be the case that others have misinterpreted your question too.

In addition, if you want to ask the editor in a comment why they made the edit, it's possible to send a comment reply (`@user`). The autocomplete won't fill in an editor's username, but they *will* receive your ping in a comment, if you do want to ask why the edit was made and clarify.

Comment: Ok, cool. I did that. Thanks for confirming my interpretation.